# fullcalendar plugin change css?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

i like to change the css. The column dayname e.g. in the agendaDay view should not be formated as bold. I can change the font-size by formating the sourrounded div. But how to change the format for a special cell?

But i didnt find the correct css entry. Anybody can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you would just need to override the style of the `<th>` element. Doesn't look like there's any custom styling applied by fullcalendar.

This css should work:

```
th {
   font-weight: normal;
}
```